# How can I create a file with a specific name

Tags: java

I need to create a file with a specific name, I want the name of the file be the year, month, hour, etc. I'm using `LocalDateTime`, and I tried to concatenate the file rute with the `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
try 
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("/C:/Users/GG/Desktop/Ejercicios/"+ldt+".txt");
    pw.write("prueba");
    pw.write("2");
    pw.close();
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\GG\Desktop\Ejercicios\2019-08-25T20:35:59.706.txt (The file name, directory name or volume label syntax is not correct)
```

Comment: Try removing the leading `/`, the one before `C:`, then make sure folder `\Users\GG\Desktop\Ejercicios` exists on the `C:` drive.

Comment: does the folder exist?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists, when I try to create a new file without the LocalDateTime it creates it with no problem, but when I try to concatenate the ldt its when it gives me the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is reserved characters in path:

> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)

you need to replace these before apply

```
String x = ldt;
//2019-08-25T20:35:59.706     Bad Form Path
String y = ldt.replace(':','')
//2019-08-25T203559.706       Well Form Path
```

or you change format like this

```
String x = ldt;
//2019-08-25T20:35:59.706
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss");
String y = ldt.format(formatter);
//2019_08_25_203559
```

Comment: Great to here that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that filenames can contain `:` in Windows, nor is it clear why your format should follow ISO-8601. I would use an explicit format without symbols, and instead of hardcoding the path I would build it relative to the user's home folder (there is a system property for that, and it works on all platforms). And, I would prefer `try-with-Resources` over explicitly closing the `PrintWriter`. Finally, if your directories do not exist the application will fail; you could create them (if they don't exist) as you go. Something like,

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File desktop = new File(home, "Desktop");
if (!desktop.exists()) {
    desktop.mkdir();
}
File ejercicios = new File(desktop, "Ejercicios");
if (!ejercicios.exists()) {
    ejercicios.mkdir();
}
String fName = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
File outFile = new File(ejercicios, String.format("%s.txt", fName));

try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile)) {
    pw.write("prueba");
    pw.write("2");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```